# Convert COUNTIFS to GETPIVOTDATA

Tags: pivot

Currently utilize the =COUNTIFS('Dec22 Pivot'!L$5:L$1195,">0",'Dec22 Pivot'!$AL$5:$AL$1195,">0") but the data does not come through in the same order each month.  This means I have to manually change the column letter every month.  Can i change this to look at the header name instead?  I can get this formula to show me the total =GETPIVOTDATA("dblQtyOrdered",'Mar23 Pivot'!$A$3,"strCategory","JF3-Flat Backed") but I can't seem to make it countif two columns have a number greater than zero.  I hope I am explaining this clear enough as I am a novice to these pivot formulas

Tried it a couple different ways, just cant figure it out